# Android not detecting my app is related to sending SMS?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that uses `SmsManager`, I have the following code to set the app as the default sms app

```
private void setDefaultSmsApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, this.getPackageName());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but the list does not contain the name of my app. I see a list of other apps related to SMS, but not my own app.

Comment: Your manifest must contain certain elements for your app to appear on the list of eligible defaults. The answer on the linked duplicate shows what is necessary.